# IQueryable with a null value

Tags: razor, asp.net-core

How can I handle null values in some of the fields when populating the IQueryable table from the db? PetIDTag can have nulls.

```
IQueryable<PetTable> petIQ= from s in _context.PetT select s;
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            petIQ = _context.PetT
                .Where(x => x.PetName.ToString() == searchString)
                    .Select(s => new PetTable
                        {
                             PetName = s.PetName,
                             PetAddress = s.PetAddress,
                             PetIDTag = s.PetIDTag.Where(x => s.PetIDTag != null)
                        });
        }
```

Comment: Your question makes no sense.  What type is `PetIDTag`? A row cannot be null.

Comment: What type is `PetIDTag`? A list, string, int etc.?

Comment: `PetIDTag` is a string from a column in the database. When populating `petIQ` and there is a null value in a string column in the database I receive a null exception error: `threw an exception of type System.NullReferenceException` I'd like to account for the null string column `PetIDTag` @SLaks @Simpy-Ged

Comment: Then calling `.Where()` on it makes no sense.  If you want to filter your entire query, add that to the query's `Where()`.

Comment: Thanks that did it. @SLaks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `.Where()` on a single value doesn't make sense.

If you want to filter your entire query, add that to the query's `Where()`.